# Управление питанием usb портов

Tags: usb, ubuntu

Как в ubuntu отключить и включить питание usb портов из терминала, если это возможно?

```
sudo echo "suspend" /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb2/2-0:1.0/power/level
```

не помогает. Так как level - нет такого файла.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте

echo -n "0" >/sys/bus/usb/devices/**device**/power/state

Comment: Не помогло. 
В .../usb2/2-0:1.0/power/   есть только файл wakeup.
В /usb2/power/ есть файлы: active_duration, autosuspend,connected_duration, level, wakeup. 

state нигде нет. 

К level в папке /usb2/power/ не доступа даже с правами суперпользователя.

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо всем за ответ(ы).Полазив немного в [документации](https://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/usb/power-management.txt) составил  ответ на вопрос.Проблема состоит в том что параметр suspend в /sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1/power/level не поддерживается,а сам файл level является аналогом файла control который поддерживает два параметра: on(всегда включён) и auto (разрешает авто выключение(файл autosuspend) если устройство не используется)( сия прелесть доступна с версии ядра 2.6.32).
Собственно само решение.
Получаем рут

```
sudo su
```

Сначала в файле control устройства ставим значение auto(разрешаем авто выключение).

```
echo auto | tee /sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1/power/control
```

Дале ставим авто выключение через ноль секунд(запись в файлик autosuspend):

```
echo 0 | tee /sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1/power/autosuspend
```

Дале отключаем(делаем его не активным):

```
echo "2-1" > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind
```

Вот и всё.
P.S.
Я думаю все понимают что вместо 2-1 должен быть путь к вашему устройству их список можно получить командой
ls /sys/bus/usb/devices/(выткните устройство, выполните команду, затем отсоедините устройство и опять выполните команду, посмотрите какое устройство пропало(это и будет нужное устройство)). Или же посмотрите

```bash
lsusb -t
```

Answer (score 0):

насколько я понимаю, это обращение уже к интерфейсу, а не к устройству:

```
/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb2/2-0:1.0
```

к устройству надо обращаться на уровень «выше»:

```
/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb2
```

его управление питанием — в каталоге `power`:

```
/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb2/power
```

---

как пишут в [этом](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12675749/4827341) и [этом](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/166601/110559) ответах, при использовании программы *linux* версии выше 2.6.38, устройства надо выключать примерно так (вместо `X` надо подставить нужный номер):

```
echo "0" > /sys/bus/usb/devices/usbX/power/autosuspend_delay_ms
echo "auto" > /sys/bus/usb/devices/usbX/power/control
```