# Как с ubuntu отключить питание на usb порт?

Tags: ubuntu

У меня есть кулер, он компьютером как отдельное устройство не определяется. Как мне отключить питание именно его usb порта?

Answer (score 0):

Решение похожего вопроса есть [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/720202/285858)
Только что проверил, на всяких мышках, флешках работает. Как будет работать с вероятно dumb вентилятором, надо смотреть, благо ссылка на документацию там есть.

Comment: Ответ-ссылка не считается ответом, а если это дубликат вопроса, то нужно отметить как дубликат

Comment: Мне с моим dumb вентилятором повторить не получилось, в /sys не появляются нужные файлы для него